# Gracefully trap error on start cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd

On a cmd prompt or bat file, I issue the following:

```
start textpad myfile.txt  and it works fine.
```

If the program textpad does not exist on the computer, then an error sound and a popup occurs which the OK button must be pushed.

I desire to trap this error so that I could do something like

```
start textpad myfile.txt || start notepad myfile.txt
```

where the || implies that if the start of textpad is not successful, then the start of notepad should occur. HOWEVER, I still get the error sound and requirement of hitting OK. 
My intent is to avoid the sound and the requirement of any user intervention.

I have also tried the following bat approach below, to no avail.

```
start textpad 
if not %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 GOTO END
start notepad
:END
```

Any help would be great.

thanks

ted

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following little snippet to find out whether the program you intend to launch exists:

```
for %%x in (textpad.exe) do set temp=%%~$PATH:x
if [%temp%]==[] echo Didn't exist.
```

But may I suggest that you simply use

```
start foo.txt
```

instead of forcing a specific editor onto the user? File type associations are there for a reason.

Comment: @jpm: Documented in `help for` at the very end. It's a bit confusing to understand. It searches a semi-colon-separated list of paths given by an environment variable (`PATH` in this case) for the filename in `%%x` and returns the full path in case such a file is found.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe you will find a way to make that work.  Perhaps look for the existence of textpad.exe on the machine?  If you can predict what directory it would be loaded from, this should be pretty easy using IF EXIST.

Answer (score 0):

There are some techniques to detect the presence of a specific tool, but this only works for command line tool, or with GUI applications also supporting command line options.

For these tricks, take a look at [this](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/autodownload.php#Detect) page.

Answer (score 0):

"/wait" parameter would do the trick for you..

```
START /wait NOTEPAD.EXE SOME.TXT
echo %ERRORLEVEL%
# This gives zero as output.

START /wait TEXTPAD.EXE SOME.TXT
echo %ERRORLEVEL%
# This gives non-zero output.
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably already have an answer, but my over-sized ego has forced me to post my answer.

So, this should work.

```
start textpad 2> nul||start notepad
```

This will start notepad if the command `start texpad` fails, while also redirecting any error message you may get from the first command.